# Spring Cloud Ilford (2020.0.3) WebClient DataBufferLimitException: Exceeded limit on max bytes to buffer

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-webclient

Spring boot 2.5.3
Spring Cloud 2020.0.3

My understanding is this was fixed in Hoxton SR7?

```
    public byte[] findImage(String guid) {
        return webClient
            .get()
            .uri(sUrl + "/findImage/" + guid )
            .header(AUTHORIZATION_PROPERTY, AUTHENTICATION_SCHEME + clientToken)
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(
                (HttpStatus::isError),
                it -> handleError(it.statusCode().getReasonPhrase()))
            .bodyToMono(FileResponse.class)
            .block(Duration.of(6000, ChronoUnit.MILLIS))
            .getContent();
    }
```

```
nested exception is org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferLimitException: Exceeded limit on max bytes to buffer : 262144
        at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException.create(WebClientResponseException.java:229)
```

Answer (score -2):

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23961

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-builder-maxinmemorysize

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class WebClientConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureHttpMessageCodecs(ServerCodecConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(16 * 1024 * 1024);
    }
}
```